# Correctly configure fetchmail/procmail to forward to gmail (with TLS)

Tags: email, gmail, fetchmail, procmail

I'll start by saying I'm pretty uninformed when it comes to mail protocols, encryption, and basically everything else relevant to this question.

My goal is to set up fetchmail/procmail on a machine to poll my exchange email and forward it to gmail (config files at the end of question). I have access to two always-on servers and I've tried setting this up on both. In both cases, fetchmail is able to successfully grab the desired e-mails, but the procmail forwarding has some undesired behavior, outlined below:

server 1: The e-mails arrive at the destination inbox (gmail) but do so without TLS encryption (as indicated by the broken red lock on gmail). The server in this scenario is a dreamhost web server. Some uninformed searching leads me to believe this is due to the fact that outgoing mail on dreamhost servers does not have TLS (http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Secure_Email). Is this indeed the likely scenario, or could this be due to my fetchmail/procmail configuration?

server 2: The e-mail is sent, but appears to be rejected by gmail. I'm coming to this conclusion based on the following log message from /var/log/mail.log

```
B8F31A6B0219: to=<gmail_username@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.68.27]:25, delay=2.5, delays=0.01/0.01/2.3/0.19, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1456578730 n203si17717347qhn.23 - gsmtp)
```

Again, is this indeed what is happening? If so, what are my troubleshooting options? Could it be that the IP is blacklisted by google and this will never work? How would one find out?

Finally, I'm open to any suggestions for how to achieve this in a different way.

.fetchmailrc

```
poll exchange.server protocol IMAP
    user "exchange_username"
    password "exchange_pass"
    smtpname "gmail_username@gmail.com"
    keep
    ssl
    no rewrite
    mda "/usr/bin/procmail -f %F -d %T"
```

.procmailrc

```
:0
! gmail_username@gmail.com
```

Comment: The log message indicates success (2xx return code). Your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the server to use TLS if that's what you want. You are not revealing which MTA you are using, but the log message looks like Postfix.  See http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html for instructions; maybe post a new question if you have trouble interpreting the guideline.